# Deploy to Azure with blob from container src url

Tags: azure, deployment

Trying to deploy, form a powershell with this kind of instruction

```
  `$outputAzWebappDeploy = az webapp deploy --resource-group $rgName --name $webAppName --`src-url $srcUrl --type zip --clean true --async true --timeout $timoutMillisecs
```

Which resolves to this kind of thing :-

```
  az webapp deploy --resource-group MYRG --name myapp --src-url "https://ourstuff.blob.core.windows.net/ourblobs/OurPackages/MYPACKAGE.zip" --type zip --clean true --async true --timeout 720000
```

The result is this kind of error in the console :-

```
This command is in preview and under development. Reference and support levels: https://aka.ms/CLI_refstatus

    Configuring default logging for the app, if not already enabled
    Zip deployment failed. {'id': 'temp-627fa3b6', 'status': 3, 'status_text': '', 'author_email': 'N/A', 'author': 'N/A', 'deployer': 'OneDeploy', 'message': 'OneDeploy', 'progress': '', 'received_time': '2023-11-02T14:23:15.2025564Z', 'start_time': '2023-11-02T14:23:15.2025564Z', 'end_time': '2023-11-02T14:23:15.3432141Z', 'last_success_end_time': None, 'complete': True, 'active': False, 'is_temp': True, 'is_readonly': False, 'url': 'https://myapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/latest', 'log_url': 'https://myapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/latest/log', 'site_name': 'myapp', 'provisioningState': 'Failed'}. Please run the command az webapp log deployment show -n myapp-g myrg
```

The command above uses --src-url, and that references a package that is downloadable via a browser.

The package in question works when I use deploy via a local package with this command :-

```
  $outputAzWebappDeploy = az webapp deploy --resource-group $rgName --name $webAppName --src-path $packagePath --type zip --clean true --async true --timeout $timoutMillisecs
```

The only difference is the use of --src-path and --src-url

And I get this kind of error, when I use --src-url :-

```
{
 'id': 'temp-12345678', 
 'status': 3, 'status_text': '',
 'author_email': 'N/A', 
 'author': 'N/A',
 'deployer': 'OneDeploy', 
 'message': 'OneDeploy', 
 'progress': '', 
 'received_time': '2023-11-02T13:19:39.8080042Z', 
 'start_time': '2023-11-02T13:19:39.8080042Z', 
 'end_time': '2023-11-02T13:19:40.0111335Z', 
 'last_success_end_time': None, 
 'complete': True, 
  'active': False, 
 'is_temp': True, 
 'is_readonly': False,
 'url': 'https://myapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/latest',
 'log_url': 'https://myapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/latest/log', 
 'site_name': 'myapp',
 'provisioningState': 'Failed'
}
```

There is nothing useful at https://myapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/latest/log

Answer (score 0):

I followed the below steps to deploy web app using **--src-url** could deploy the application successfully.

- Uploaded a **Zip file of my Dotnet web application** to **Azure Storage Container**.

[image]

```
$srcUrl=https://<storage_account>.blob.core.windows.net/container/blob/WebApplication14.zip
```

- Created a **Windows web application** with **dotnet** as runtime stack in Azure Portal.
- Deploying the application from **Storage Blob** to **Azure App Service** using the same command you provided:

```
$outputAzWebappDeploy = az webapp deploy --resource-group $rgName --name srcurlwebapp --src-url "https://<storage_account>.blob.core.windows.net/container/WebApplication14.zip" --type zip --clean true --async true --timeout 720000
```

Checking the status by running `$outputAzWebappDeploy`, could see the `ProvisionState` status as `InProgress`.

[image]

- Navigate to `https://<webapp_name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments`, to check the `ProvisingState` status:

[image]

- I could see the application got **deployed** by navigating to `KUDU site(App Service=> Advanced Tools=>Go)=>Debug Console=>CMD=>Site=>wwwroot`:

[image]

- **Response of log_url** `https://<webapp_name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/2ebf157d1154487b9adc5832ea933702/log`:

```json
[
    {
        "log_time": "2023-11-08T09:52:53.8746677Z",
        "id": "305ca616-6772-470e-9195-1bc898d90670",
        "message": "Updating submodules.",
        "type": 0,
        "details_url": null
    },
    {
        "log_time": "2023-11-08T09:52:53.9197957Z",
        "id": "fc1ea239-de3f-4992-81a1-d2681b73209e",
        "message": "Preparing deployment for commit id '2ebf157d11'.",
        "type": 0,
        "details_url": null
    },
    {
        "log_time": "2023-11-08T09:52:54.0604276Z",
        "id": "705d30f6-57e4-4a1c-a4e1-4b357f225ec3",
        "message": "Running build. Project type: OneDeploy",
        "type": 0,
        "details_url": null
    },
    {
        "log_time": "2023-11-08T09:52:54.107305Z",
        "id": "785ee1bf-c2cd-4d21-a2b3-ceaef8ab69cd",
        "message": "Copying the manifest",
        "type": 0,
        "details_url": null
    },
    {
        "log_time": "2023-11-08T09:52:54.1542099Z",
        "id": "1dfb9f61-5f2f-4336-9190-a94a789defcb",
        "message": "Clean deploying to C:\\home\\site\\wwwroot",
        "type": 0,
        "details_url": null
    },
    {
        "log_time": "2023-11-08T09:52:54.2010638Z",
        "id": "cd683472-0891-4bc7-960a-f60ca0f8cd05",
        "message": "Generating deployment script.",
        "type": 0,
        "details_url": "https://<webapp_name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/2ebf157d1154487b9adc5832ea933702/log/cd683472-0891-4bc7-960a-f60ca0f8cd05"
    },
    {
        "log_time": "2023-11-08T09:52:54.279199Z",
        "id": "27264739-4671-4f2b-8ff0-ba1b831ffa82",
        "message": "Running deployment command...",
        "type": 0,
        "details_url": "https://<webapp_name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/2ebf157d1154487b9adc5832ea933702/log/27264739-4671-4f2b-8ff0-ba1b831ffa82"
    },
    {
        "log_time": "2023-11-08T09:52:55.9667751Z",
        "id": "a98e5204-47b0-4810-b6fb-8e22cba434bd",
        "message": "Build completed succesfully.",
        "type": 0,
        "details_url": null
    },
    {
        "log_time": "2023-11-08T09:52:56.0294204Z",
        "id": "d266a222-b8d2-4ae9-85e2-2b537113adb7",
        "message": "Running post deployment command(s)...",
        "type": 0,
        "details_url": null
    },
    {
        "log_time": "2023-11-08T09:52:56.1074763Z",
        "id": "18345217-e5b8-403c-9285-b404a6384b19",
        "message": "Requesting site restart",
        "type": 0,
        "details_url": null
    },
    {
        "log_time": "2023-11-08T09:52:56.1699214Z",
        "id": "e3c5351c-5481-4609-8a8f-bda17537c3ad",
        "message": "Requesting site restart. Attempt #1",
        "type": 0,
        "details_url": null
    },
    {
        "log_time": "2023-11-08T09:52:56.341793Z",
        "id": "9c5d1f5a-2880-4766-aa33-be6eb98dab3a",
        "message": "Successfully requested a restart. Attempt #1",
        "type": 0,
        "details_url": null
    },
    {
        "log_time": "2023-11-08T09:52:56.404298Z",
        "id": "aa47ea26-ab4b-41cc-88e4-9568184d9fab",
        "message": "Deployment successful.",
        "type": 0,
        "details_url": null
    }
]
```